# is car idling bad for 21st century modern day car?

Tags: sparkplugs, rough-idle, idle, hunting-idle

I have a 2016 Toyota corolla.

I hardly drive anywhere.

I have around 92000 km on the odometer.

I live in Canada, and therefore, the winters are extremely cold.

When winter is in full swing, I turn on my car, and let it sit idle for like 15 mins.

Recently, I had to change my spark plugs twice in a short time period of like 8 months.

I hardly drive anywhere, and I drive cautiously.

Do you think my lenghty car idling during winter caused my spark plugs to burn out?

Comment: Why did you have to change the spark plugs twice in 8 months? Most vehicles made since OBDII became a thing, have spark plugs which should last 100k miles (160,000 km) or longer, regardless of time. Your vehicle doesn't 1/2 that amount of mileage.

Comment: The mechanic used an OBDII scan for my car in front me.  The OBDII scanner stated that Cylinder 2 misfired.  We both took a look at the spark plugs, and they were burn out.  We had to replace them.  It was pricy.  We replaced all four.  IT cost me CAD 192 including taxes.  Ouch.   Yikes

Comment: Occasional driving and only idling your car in winter without driving doesn't wear out spark plugs. However, plug fouling can occur with only idling as the engine just warms up before shutdown. Cold engines use rich fuel mixtures that can foul plugs with dry or wet black deposits if a vehicle isn't driven more than 15 minutes when engines burn off condensation absorbed in motor oil. If you can, drive once or twice a month for 30-60 minutes each time.

Comment: CAD 192? I guess a large proportion of that is the diagnostic fee.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Relative to Americans, we Canadians are taxed highly, and a lot of products and services are expensive.  There is Not much competition in business.  However, we have government-backed healthcare, and our jobs are usually stable in the sense that there are Not may layoffs compared to Americans.  Oh Well, we can Not have everything.  LOL :)

Comment: I was just saying – 4 spark plugs and fitting isn't a huge job itself. But there is often a hefty fee (in UK) for the diagnostic.